# 2.79 vs. 2.8 F6 key to recall menu

Tags: modeling, interface

When I add a new shape a context window shows up with some useful settings to the new object, but as soon as I move or pan, or even accidentally, such additional menu disappears.

In the 2.79 Blender I used <kbd>F6</kbd> key to recall it.
How about the new release?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The shortcut is <kbd>F9</kbd> or you can access it through *Edit > Adjust Last Operation*.

[image]

Quoting from the [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/undo_redo.html#adjust-last-operation):

> After an operation is complete you can tweak the parameters of the operation afterwards. In editors that support it, there is a “head-up display” panel in the bottom left based on the last performed operation; dependent on mode and context. Alternatively, you can create a pop-up with <kbd>F9</kbd> which does the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

I don't want to tell you something wrong but for what I found, it's like they removed this thing.

I found the proof here: https://cgcookie.com/t/1340-ended-bc1-1808-august-2018-class-homepage-getting-started-with-3d-modeling-blender-2-8?page=4

Saying:

> " When you start to use an operator, the appropriate floating Operator
>   Panel - the one you used to have to call up by tapping F6 - now
>   appears in the viewport automatically.  There is no docked panel in
>   the Toolbar anymore. "

Hope that I didn't tell you something wrong

Comment: The panel is just at a slightly different position now, no functionality has changed. Nothing is removed. The options disappear after you perform another action in previous versions as well.

Comment: Well OP was asking how to recall it and I says that the functionality of recalling it was removed, I didn't say that they removed it all, if it's in a different position it's another thing.. can't understand why my answer was not useful

Comment: The functionality to call the panel was not removed. F6 hotkey was removed from default keymap, but the functionality is still there and you can set up a new hotkey in 4 clicks. [See this answer.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129015/where-is-the-operator-panel-in-blender-2-8/129016#129016)