# Where is the operator panel in Blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling

The tutorial I read is based on 2.79. So I'm not sure if it's still the same name in 2.8. But I can't find anything providing similar functionalities.

Comment: [Blender 2.8 onwards the default shortcut](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/interface/undo_redo.html#adjust-last-operation) to access this is _F9_ not _F6_.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be found in the 3d Viewport:

[image]

As well as in the *Edit* menu where it is called *Adjust Last Operation* now, where you can also right click it and choose *Assign Shortcut* if you wanted to be able to call it with a keyboard shortcut like it was with <kbd>F6</kbd> in previous versions:

[image]

Obviously, it does not need to be <kbd>F6</kbd> and could be anything that is convenient to you.

Comment: This is very similar to [How to reduce poly number when you start creating object in 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126568/how-to-reduce-poly-number-when-you-start-creating-object-in-2-8/126570#comment219685_126570) , however I think the question is formed a lot clearer so I think it makes sense to have a clear question and answer here to be able to link all the possible duplicate variations of it in the future.