# How do you Adjust the number of vertices when creating a circle?

Tags: modeling

The new blender 2.8 is different. When I create a circle there is no longer an option to adjust the number of verticies in the circle. Even when I press F6 av

Comment: The panel is bottom-down, you need to deploy it like shown here,
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129015/where-is-the-operator-panel-in-blender-2-8

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom-left and above the time line, you may need to deploy the panel (small arrow).

[image]