# Mesh subdivide x&y indepenently

Tags: mesh

I need to subdivide a pre-existing mesh grid with different values for x & y (like I could in pre-2.8). Is this possible in 2.8? I have looked through the UI and searched online for a few hours...nothing so far.

Comment: How did you do this pre 2.8?

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129015/where-is-the-operator-panel-in-blender-2-8

Comment: in pre-2.8 I Add > Mesh > Grid then text boxes appear in bottom left of tools panel "Add Grid" with options for X Subdivisions, Y Subdivisions, Radius, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER (to my own question):
It's in 'Edit Mode' Add > Grid then "Add a Grid" box pops up with x and y subdivision text boxes like in pre-2.8. (I just could not find out how to access this box in 2.8 before posting the question)

[image]

Comment: isn't that what Ray suggested to you in comments? Also it is not in edit mode only you can access it from object mode as well.

Comment: Not quite, I added the comment about "Add > Mesh > Grid" concerning what I did pre 2.8. This solution is quicker. Also, Edit Mode must be used since an existing object is being edited - a new object is not being added. This is a very simple solution - 1 step. I have already done it and it works flawlessly. The other solution is unnecessarily complicated for something that only needs 1 step.

Comment: Add grid doesn't edit an existing object in edit mode.  It adds grid mesh to existing edit objects mesh. (_possibly giving the appearance of editing the mesh on overlay_)

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by subdividing one direction at a time. You can do so by first selecting two opposite edges, and subdividing them. Then, select the new grid lines by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and clicking on one of the grid lines. Then subdivide that.

[image]

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: Awesome, probably not the fastest way for the Q, but I never thought I can subdivide in that way - like LoopCut but on one face. BTW gif is bad I don't see what is going on there. Better record in wire mode, on grey  face the lines are not visible.

Comment: @vklidu It's just selecting the opposite edges and subdividing. When you do that, Blender will automatically fill in the lines. The thing is when you're doing it for the second direction, you're going to need to select all the parallel lines and run subdivide again. That's all the whole Ctrl+Alt+Click selection is about.

Comment: I got it , but I had to try it by my self. From your A I didn't know edge is filled automatically, you didn't wrote about it and it is not visible from gif.  Small things, but broke my imaginery - what happens. So if i m not the only one, so also others will appreciate some adjustment of your A.

Comment: @vklidu Alright, let me know if this one helps

Comment: IMO this answers the question as stated perfectly and subdivides a pre-existing mesh grid with different x and y.  After seeing OP's answer, understandably had to vote to close as dupe.