# How do I extrude a cylinder at an angle?

Tags: extrude

Blender 3.0

Object mode: Add > Mesh > Cylinder > F9 > Cap Fill Type: Nothing => Creates a cylinder open on both ends

Scene: Units: Imperial - Length: inches ... N: X: 0.9" - Y: 0.8" - Z: 1"

Edit mode: Edge Region icon, then Edge select icon > drag mouse over top half > drag yellow dot up.

[image]

I know the Z of 109.51 is incorrect.  However, how do I extrude the hollow cylinder at an angle (not straight up)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to adjust the direction in the *Extrude Tool* menu.

[image]

Comment: I am unable to drag sideways.  I've tried both Vertex Select and Edge Select.  I'm using Blender 3.0.  I see a Tranform Menu ... do not have a Extrude Region menu.

Comment: Hi :). Not sure what you mean by "drag sideways". Simply extrude a bit and then control it using the menu :)

Comment: I do not have an "Extrude Region and Move" menu.  Are are you using Blender 3.0?

Comment: Yes sir, Blender 3.0 or any other version [since 2.8 has this menu](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/129015/78972). It's pretty vital for precise adjustments ;)

Comment: How do I have the "Extrude Region and Move" menu appear?  An icon?  A keyboard letter?

Comment: @ttom Take a look at the screenshot. He chose the _Extrude Region_ tool on the left. And of course you have to be in _Edit Mode_. It's quite handy, although I wouldn't say it's vital ;)

Comment: @ttom if you don't see the menu, just follow the link in my comment to enable it ;)

Comment: Jachym Michal, I viewed that link.  My bottom left screen is blank.  I do not have that option.

Comment: Gordon Brinkmann, When I select Extrude Region, the "Extrude Region and Move" menu does not appear.  What setting would cause it to appear?

Comment: Hey :). You probably disabled it by accident. It's in Edit > Adjust last operation

Comment: Edit > Adjust works  ...  an important detail!

Comment: @ttom sorry about that, it's supposed to be enabled by default, didn't cross my mind it would be missing ;). anyways, good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a rotation with your extrusion, you could take a look at using the  *Spin* tool, invoked either by direct <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>  > *Spin* shortcut, or from the <kbd>T</kbd> toolbar, which provides a gizmo. The origin of rotation is initially at the 3D Cursor, but can be adjusted in the <kbd>F9</kbd> 'Adjust Last Operation' panel.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Summary: create a dummy face to set the desired angle and use it to set a Transform Orientation before extruding.

Steps:

1. Select your object
2. Go to Edit Mode
3. Create a 4-vertex plane (that you can delete after ward)
4. Angle it as desired
5. Make sure the plane face is selected
6. Add a new Transform Orientation
7. Extrude the desired vertices on the rest of the geometry using the proper Axis (most likely Z)
8. Delete the dummy plane

[image]
[image]

Comment: What keystrokes add the 4-vertex plane?

Comment: Shift-A Add Plane!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: use an Edge, Vertex or 3D-Cursor as pivot point

Steps:

1. Select your edge loop, making sure the active edge or vertex is the one to use as pivot point
2. set the Transform Pivot Point as "Active Element" (or 3D-Cursor if placed properly)
3. Extrude without moving
4. Rotate the extruded geometry

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used the Jachym Michal answer.  *Edit > Adjust* allows the ability to move the selection sideways.

This sequence works too *Edge Select* icon (next to *Edit Mode*) drag mouse over top area, <kbd>Right Click</kbd>, extrude edges, drag up and sideways.