# Unable to reset default properties of new mesh using "Adjust Last Operation..."

Tags: mesh

If I create a new mesh (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>), it appears onscreen. If I then press <kbd>F9</kbd> (the "Adjust Last Operation..." option under "Edit"), the add object menu appears and lets me change the properties of the new object:

[image]

When I create a new object, the properties are the same as the previous object.

If I wanted to reset these back to the system default (without resetting the whole app to factory settings), how would I do that? If I right-click in the add object menu, the option to reset to default is disabled:

[image]

I've ensured global undo is enabled.

Comment: Yes that's weird because if you use the Operator box (without pressing F9) you have access to the reset

Comment: Ah - I wasn't able to find the operator box which is why I was using F9. Found it after you mentioned it from [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129015/where-is-the-operator-panel-in-blender-2-8). You're right, I can reset using the regular Operator box.

Comment: @TomSelleck Stupid question: you're not "the" Tom Selleck, or are you? ;) But as moonboots said, it seems that the F9 menu is different than the operator box which opens up directly. For one, the F9 menu cannot be collapsed... and it's not that it might have "forgotten" the default. When you open the F9 menu while the operator box is still open, you cannot reset the F9 menu values, but the ones from the operator box.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Movies don't pay as well as they used to  

Oh well, the operator box will do the job fine now that I've found it

Comment: @TomSelleck Yes, of course it will... I was just thinking aloud about this F9 menu :D Seems like the operator box has default values to which you can reset, and maybe the F9 menu is just given the values from the operator but possesses no defaults on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears the "Adjust last operation" menu doesn't support setting mesh properties back to global default. Not sure if this is a bug or not...

Solution is to use the Operator Box instead:

[image]